# unable to run "docker-compose up" after replaced Docker Desktop for Windows by Docker Toolbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-compose

Scenario: I had my docker-compose.yml working as expected when I was using Docker Desktop For Windows (here is Windows 10 Pro). Since I had to use also Virtual Box + Minishift in same Notebook I read somewhere else recommending to uninstall Docker Desktop for Windows and install Docker Toolbox (basically because Docker Descktop rely on HyperV and I can't start Virtual Box & Minishift if I don't desable HyperV). So far so good. I mean, I successfully start minishift (OpenShift simplified version) and I successfully started docker.

The problem is that after I unistalled Docker For Windows and I installed Docker ToolBox I am getting the error pasted bellow.

It seems some issue while "mounting" the volumes or some problem with certain path but I can imagine what I may try to fix.

In case it matter, I add here also my entire docker-compose and all its yml and conf files dependency. If you want to reproduce, all files pasted bellow can be cloned from [github](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/DockerComposeLogs)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml"
    restart: always
    environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=kibana.localhost
    - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - "./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./logstash.conf:/config-dir/logstash.conf"
    restart: always
    command: logstash -f /config-dir/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
      - "7777:7777"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    command: [start-kafka.sh]
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  kafka3:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9094:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka3:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  zoo1:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 1
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  zoo2:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 2
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2182:2181"
  zoo3:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 3
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2183:2181"
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro"
      - "./sample-logs:/sample-logs"
    links:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
```

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:

- paths:
    - /sample-logs/*.log
  tags:
    - request-sample
  input_type: log
  document_type: request-sample
  fields_under_root: true

output.kafka:
  hosts: ["kafka1:9092", "kafka2:9092", "kafka3:9092"]
  topic: 'log'
  partition.round_robin:
    reachable_only: false
  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 1000000
```

kibana.yml

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: false
#opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: false
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
```

logstash.conf

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092"
    client_id => "logstash"
    group_id => "logstash"
    consumer_threads => 3
    topics => ["log"]
    codec => "json"
    tags => ["log", "kafka_source"]
    type => "log"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "request-sample" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
      match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
      remove_field => ["timestamp"]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
       index => "logstash-%{[type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Logs trying docker-compose -up

```
SPANOT149+Cast@SPANOT149 MINGW64 /c/Dockers/megalog-try-1 (master)
$ docker-compose down                                                                                                   Stopping megalog-try-1_logstash_1 ... done                                                                              Stopping megalog-try-1_kafka2_1   ... done                                                                              Stopping megalog-try-1_kafka3_1   ... done                                                                              Stopping megalog-try-1_kafka1_1   ... done                                                                              Stopping megalog-try-1_zoo3_1     ... done                                                                              Stopping megalog-try-1_zoo2_1     ... done                                                                              Stopping megalog-try-1_zoo1_1     ... done                                                                              Removing megalog-try-1_logstash_1      ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_filebeat_1      ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_kibana_1        ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_zoo3_1          ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_elasticsearch_1 ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_zoo2_1          ... done                                                                         Removing megalog-try-1_zoo1_1          ... done                                                                         Removing network megalog-try-1_default

SPANOT149+Cast@SPANOT149 MINGW64 /c/Dockers/megalog-try-1 (master)
$ docker volume prune
WARNING! This will remove all local volumes not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Volumes:
10a8f1ae070802866a7072ded8a65fb8cee80fbbcf527126869a69778089d514
f71c1e6bd951a256cf746d538528baa9f34b0da57ca628f03fbabbb1eb9c1133
0d8ed8cff8f2cdd1870f4f3757d15203432b9a549d13d9094c090a41f11e66c5

Total reclaimed space: 62.92MB

SPANOT149+Cast@SPANOT149 MINGW64 /c/Dockers/megalog-try-1 (master)
$ docker container prune
WARNING! This will remove all stopped containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B

SPANOT149+Cast@SPANOT149 MINGW64 /c/Dockers/megalog-try-1 (master)
$ docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
Creating network "megalog-try-1_default" with the default driver
Creating megalog-try-1_zoo3_1          ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_zoo2_1          ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_elasticsearch_1 ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_zoo1_1          ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ...
Creating megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ...
Creating megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ...
Creating megalog-try-1_kibana_1        ... error                                                                        
ERROR: for megalog-try-1_kibana_1  Cannot start service kibana: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Dockers/Creating megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ... done                                                                         ing to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
Creating megalog-try-1_logstash_1      ...
Creating megalog-try-1_filebeat_1      ... error                                                                        
ERROR: for megalog-try-1_filebeat_1  Cannot start service filebeat: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/filebeat.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/445ddec2e92149c077681b1daf3f0723dbc3c3f821541fb28252501ae122a4bf/merged\\\" at \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/445ddec2e92149c077681b1daf3f0723dbc3c3f821541fb28252501ae122a4bf/merged/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you Creating megalog-try-1_logstash_1      ... done                                                                         e

ERROR: for kibana  Cannot start service kibana: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/kibana.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/36dbfb01925aef8cc05376a57e88d2f7e3b85bd47af9549e13a9c4f5ad516ae3/merged\\\" at \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/36dbfb01925aef8cc05376a57e88d2f7e3b85bd47af9549e13a9c4f5ad516ae3/merged/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for filebeat  Cannot start service filebeat: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/filebeat.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/445ddec2e92149c077681b1daf3f0723dbc3c3f821541fb28252501ae122a4bf/merged\\\" at \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/445ddec2e92149c077681b1daf3f0723dbc3c3f821541fb28252501ae122a4bf/merged/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

SPANOT149+Cast@SPANOT149 MINGW64 /c/Dockers/megalog-try-1 (master)
```

Comment: You probably have to go download docker-compose again since it would have been deleted after you did an upgrade IF you placed the executable in Docker's working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Docker toolbox shares the `c:\Users` (case sensitive) directory into the VM for containers to access as volumes. You need to add additional shares in VirtualBox to the VM to mount other paths as a volume:

> 1. Open the VirtualBox UI.
> 2. Click the Settings gear, then go to Shared Folders.
> 3. Select any existing listing under Machine Folders, then click the + icon.
>
>    - Choose the Folder Path on the host, enter the Folder Name for within the VM (or take the default, which is the same name as on the
>        host), and configure any additional options you need.
>    - Choose Auto-mount if you want the folder to automatically be mounted into the VM, and choose Make Permanent for it to be considered
>        a permanently shared folder.
> 4. Click OK to add the new folder to the Shared Folders list.
> 5. Click OK again to save your changes and exit the Settings dialog.

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#optional-add-shared-directories